# How do I automatically protect the integrity of an `index` column on a doctrine entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm aware that there are extensions for Doctrine that manage tree / nested set behaviors, but that seems very much overkill for what I want.

I simply have a model called `Faq` with the fields `question`, `answer` and `number`, `createdAt` and `updatedAt`. The `number` column is used to be able to edit the order the questions appear in on the page.

And I'm using `EasyAdminBundle` to provide a simple admin panel for my client to edit the FAQ with.

Now here's the thing, let's say there are 5 questions and the client wants to make the 5th question the 3rd question. What I would like is that he can just simply edit the 5th question's `number` field with the value `3` and that all the other `number` fields of the other entities automatically adjust to this change. So 3 and 4 now become 4 and 5 respectively.

I'm assuming I need some kind of event listener for this, but I can't quite figure out what kind.

All I've figured out so far is that once I have the right event listener, I should do this when it executes:

```php
function updateNumbers(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $faqRepo = $em->getRepository(Faq::class);
    $faqs = $faqRepo->findAll();
    // ^ that is already correctly sorted, based on number and updatedAt

    foreach($faqs as $i => $faq) {
        $faq->setNumber($i+1);
    }

    $em->flush();
}
```

Now I just need to know how to make sure that that function is triggered at the right moment. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

With the code you wrote you should probably go for a `postFlush` even, but be aware that calling `$em->flush()` from the event listener will trigger the event yet again so you need to have a recursion guard. You may also want to write additional logic that will run the re-index logic only if a position of certain post actually did changed.

For a slightly simpler approach you could hook into a `preUpdate` event. When a `number` of an entry changes, you fire a DB query that will update all entries with `number` greater than or equal to the new value and increase their `number` by 1.

Comment: But wouldn't the preUpdate event have the same infinite recurrence issue?

Comment: No because during preUpdate you'd issue a DB query, not a flush

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it by doing the following:

```php
// src/EventListener/FaqSorter.php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Faq;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\FaqRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class FaqSorter
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PostUpdate
     * @ORM\PostRemove
     */
    function updateNumbers(Faq $faq, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        static $hasRun = false;

        // This is not the prettiest solution to prevent recurrence,
        // but AFAIK I never need to run this more than once per request.
        if ($hasRun) return;

        $em = $event->getEntityManager();

        /** @var FaqRepository $faqRepo */
        $faqRepo = $em->getRepository(get_class($faq));
        $faqs = $faqRepo->findAll();
        // ^ that is already correctly sorted, based on number and updatedAt

        if ($faq->getNumber() === null) {
            // If the number was null then this was triggered
            // by a PrePersist event and then I'll just
            // put it at the end of the list.
            return $faq->setNumber(count($faqs) + 1);
        }

        foreach($faqs as $i => $faq) {
            $faq->setNumber($i+1);
        }

        $hasRun = true;

        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

And then in `config/services.yaml`:

```
services:
    # ...

    App\EventListener\FaqSorter:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

And in the `src/Entity/Faq.php`:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FaqRepository")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"App\EventListener\FaqSorter"})
 */
class Faq {
    // ...
}
```